# How to set data to new elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add data to new elements if I use `$.each` and string variable?

I know how to do if I use data attribute

```
var str = '';
$.each(data.list, function(i,r){
    str += '<div data-one="' + r.one + '">Element</div>';
})
$('body').append(str);
```

How to do if I want to use `$.data` in this case?

```
$.data(div, "data", {
  one: r.one,
  two: r.two
})
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is `div` in your second example?

Comment: @FelixKling, just example, I can't use it because it's string.

Comment: So `div` is basically the same as `str`? That was the missing piece of information. (I guess it's clear from reading the question completely but not from glancing over the code)

Comment: @FelixKling `str` can be like this `str = '<div data-one="' + r.one + '">Element</div><div data-one="' + r.one + '">Element</div><div data-one="' + r.one + '">Element</div><div data-one="' + r.one + '">Element</div><div data-one="' + r.one + '">Element</div>`  Few divs. And I need to set data for every div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you **must** create all divs with a long string, use a second `$.each-loop` to find the divs and set data on them:

```
var str = ''; $.each(/* your code */); $('body').append(str);

// find all divs with a data-one-attribute and iterate over them
$('body div[data-one]').each(function(i, div) {
    var d = data.list[i]; // find the associated item of data.list
    $.data(div, 'data', {one: d.one, two: d.two}); // set the data on this div
});
```

A shorter way creates inside your `$.each()` at each step a real div-element, sets the data on it and adds the div to an jQuery object. Afterwards the upfilled jQ object is appended to body:

```
var divs = $(); // create an empty jQuery object being the container
$.each(data.list, function(i, r) {
    var d = $('<div data-one="' + r.one + '">Element</div>'); // create one div-element
    // since d is an jQuery object, use d.data() to set the data on it:
    d.data('data', {one: r.one, two: r.two});
    divs.add(d); // put the div into the container
});
$('body').append(divs); // append the whole container to body
```

If you want to use `$.data()` in the second solution, just replace `d.data(...)` with:

```
$.data(d[0], 'data', {one: r.one, two: r.two});
```

Comment: Awesome idea with `divs = $();` Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To use jquery Data you can't do the divs in a string, you can do this inside the each function.

Var a=[] ;
a.push($('div', {text:'element'} ).data({one:1,two:2})

And then append the a.

Comment: `Array.push` is not a function that exists.